# Use win8 simulator for developing Win8 apps on Win7?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, simulator

I installed VS 11 ultimate on my win7 machine but I don't have metro style templates. Would I  have it only in win8 machine?

I want to develop Metro app for win8, is there is any way to use win8 simulator for that (like you have for android, so you don't really need a device, you can use the simulator for developing)?

Answer (score 5):

There's no such option.  You need to use Win8 to develop Metro apps.  You can do it in a virtual machine if necessary though

Comment: I tried running VM on Mac. `Virtual Box` and `VMWare Fusion 4` work ok. Virtual Box is free.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how you want to run them, you won't be able to develop the metro app in the first place because you won't have the WinRT API available on your Win7 machine to compile against. Microsoft has no plans to support that option in the future.

For reference the Win8 simulator is simply a customised remote desktop connection to your local machine, so it wouldn't have helped in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot develop apps targeting Windows 8 new features on a Windows 7 machine. VS 2012 works fine in Windows 7, but for every app type but Metro style.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a VHD as recommended by Scott Hanselman right [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToGuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8ConsumerPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx), this way you are running it directly on your hardware without loosing your Windows 7 installation.